# Why hg does not clones correctly the repository?

Tags: mercurial, repository, branch, clone

I have a repository which will be cloned.
I go to directory of the repository and type the following command to get the branches.

```
hg branches
```

As the reuslt I get the

```
blank                          0:4d82003d3fc7
```

And also I get the size of the repository using

```
du -sh ./
```

It prints

```
312M    ./
```

This repository containes the following.

```
ls -a
.  ..  dummy  .hg  .hglf
```

Now when I clone it using this command

```
hg clone /path/libname -r blank
```

I get the new repository, the size of which is only `52 kbts` and it containes

```
.  ..  dummy  .hg  .hglf
```

I also clone it without `-r blank` option

```
hg clone /path/libname
```

And get the same result. I suppose if repository have 312M size, the cloned repository also should have a comparable size. Where is a problem ?

Comment: Is the `blank` branch only at revision 0? Because that's what the output of `hg branches` seems to indicate.

Comment: Yes it is, here only one revision 0.

Comment: So that one revision consists of 312MB of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original repository has a '.hglf' file. This indicates that (most likely) it uses 'largefiles'. Largefiles are stored on the server, and are only downloaded for a specific revision if you update to that revision. There are a few possibilities:

1. You are not on a revision that uses largefiles. Update to one that does and you'll see a larger size.
2. You don't have the 'largefiles extension' enabled. Enable it and try to clone again, you should see a difference. To enable largefiles, add to your .hgrc:

   `[extensions]
    largefiles =`

Starting with Mercurial 3.4 (not yet released as of this writing), the largefiles extension will be enabled automatically when cloning a repository with largefiles.